# Simplest way to modify a vue.js SPA so that Google has the ability to Scan its content

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, single-page-application

I have just completed and deployed a vue.js SPA with an express back-end, just to realise that Google bots cannot scan its content. What would be the simplest method (and involving as less code modification as possible) to modify the application so that Google can scan it (as there appears to be many different ways in achieving this)?

Thank you. J

Comment: *Google bots cannot scan its content* - why?

Comment: Since it is a Single Page Application, in which all the HTML is rendered via JavaScript (and thus Google only sees an empty template at first).

Comment: yeah, sorry, had a brainfart moment - search for "SPA SEO" - there's much information out there - Server Side Rendering seems to be the best option

Comment: Yes thanks @JaromandaX I had done some reading but SSR appears to involve quite a bit of code modification. I was wondering if there were any easier way.

Comment: do the search I suggested and you'll see

Comment: Try this, they will prerender your content to serve the Googlebots. https://prerender.io/

Comment: Interesting. Thank you @MataPrasadChauhan

Comment: Give a try to those 3 answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A8816585+prerender Overall, Nuxt is still the most flexible and customisable solution (and is a pretty quick/simple migration). TLDR: Google is able to crawl an SPA but the SEO will indeed be subpar compared to some SSR'ed content.